# Convert to class field from a string in Play template

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I have a model in play framework

```
public class XYZ extends Model
{
    @Id 
    public int a; 
    public String field1; 
    public String field2; 
}
```

In my `index.scala.html` I need to generate `field1` and `field2` dynamically.
I have an object `xyz` of `XYZ` class.
I need to get the value of `xyz.field1`.
I generate the string `field1` dynamically in my code using `"field".concat("1")` and now I need to convert this string to a field so as to call `xyz.field1`.
I am not able to figure out how to do this conversion in my `scala.html` file.

Comment: Because Scala (and thus Play 2 templates) are statically typed you will have trouble with this kind of thing. One option might be to add a method to your class that converts it's fields to a Map, and then access that with your dynamically-generated keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use reflections to get a field by its name, even in a template.

```
 @classof[XYZ].getField("field" + fieldNum).get(xyz)
```

If you have only a two fields, a simple if/else would probably a better way to get the fields values. If it's more complex create a method in your model and use some `switch` statement or a map, like *Mikesname* suggested.